# Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code EHOSTUNREACH

Tags: node.js, angular, angularjs

npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/thunky fallied,reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH 2000:4700:8393:88e2:e439:41d:6810:1023:443
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!
Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic failed, see above.

Angular installing problem

Comment: Look here. Eventually it will helps: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6820